# JPA - Returning entities that are After StartDate and Before EndDate

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have two dates in my entity. ie.

```
Date startDate;
Date endDate;
```

How do I query so that given a date, it will return all entities where the specified date lies between   `startDate` and `endDate`?

I already tried the following:

```
findByStartDateAfterAndEndDateBefore(Date givenDate);
```

And Spring-Data-JPA didn't like this and running into errors. There is no specific error and the repo just can't be injected to my class.

What is the correct way?  I know this can be done easily wqith Hibernate criteria or with Native SQL but trying to do that in Spring JPA.

Is this a problem with the query itself or some sort of incompatibility between the Date types Spring uses?

Tried `findByStartDateAfterAndEndDateBefore(Date givenDate, Date givenDate)` and that returns null however.

Comment: `findByStartDate...   JPA didnt like this`. There is a reason JPA didnt like it; the JPA API does not have anything to do with methods starting findXXX. That is Spring Data JPA API. Totally different API

Comment: @DN1 Yeah, tagged Spring JPA api. Thanks for the edit anyway.

Comment: Is the field you check for `startDate` and `endDate` just a date, or does it contain contain time data as well?

Comment: @Just date is fine. I am not really needed the time. 00:00:00 is fine.

Comment: What version of spring data JPA are you using? What is the exact type of `Date`? Is it `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date`?

Comment: As I said, it returns empty. However less than and greater than works.. looks so strange. It is `java.util.Date` and `Spring Data JPA 1.10`

Answer (score 23):

You can't use only one parameter because of Spring Data restrictions, but you can workaround it using code like this:

```
List<AnEntity> findByStartDateBeforeAndEndDateAfter(Date startDate, Date endDate);

default List<AnEntity> findByStartDateBeforeAndEndDateAfter(Date givenDate) {
    return findByStartDateBeforeAndEndDateAfter(givenDate, givenDate);
}
```

This code should cover your needs. I also verified it with Spring Boot 1.5.9. using [spring-data-get-started example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/).

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question that I have tried using `findByStartDateAfterAndEndDateBefore(Date givenDate, Date givenDate)`

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer this is the working code, it follows the documentation and I verified it on real example. Try to copy-paste it, it might be that you made a typo while checking.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Could the problem be that you have swapped the 'After' and 'Before' predicates in your method name? The method name must be findByStartDate**Before**AndEndDate**After**.

Comment: As I said, it returns empty. However less than and greater than works.. looks so strange.

Comment: if given dates are same what will be result.

Answer (score 6):

To my surprise `LessThan` and `GreaterThan` working and `Before` and `After` failing badly.

I never thought I can use less than and greater than for dates and always look at date related functions like between, before, after.

That's mostly because of the documentation example

```
After

findByStartDateAfter

… where x.startDate > ?1

Before

findByStartDateBefore

… where x.startDate < ?1
```

So I looked more close into docs of [Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) and found something interesting with the below example

```
 LocalDate date = new LocalDate().minusYears(2);
 return builder.lessThan(root.get(_Customer.createdAt), date);
```

So while comparing datatime the authors using the criteria `lessthan` for time property.

So given a shot with less than and worked and again gave a shot with greater than aswell and later together. So I came up with a conclusion

```
public MyDateEntity findByStartDateLessThanAndEndDateGreaterThan(Date sDate, Date eDate);
```

And this is working so far. And I believe,  there must be a clean way to handle dates probably with `before,after,between` but I just can't figure that out.

Would be great if someone figure that out.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `AND` condition in your JPA query but providing only one parameter. You should use like `findByStartDateAfterAndEndDateBefore(Date startDate, Date endDate);`

Comment: I want records that lies between the given date.

Comment: between what given date ? to get "between" data you have to have two dates

Comment: It's the reverse case what I needed. I give the date, and need all the entities, that start date > than given and < end date.

Comment: Ok, In this case you can pass same date values in both argument. Like `findByStartDateAfterAndEndDateBefore(Date givenDate, Date givenDate)`

Comment: Or create a default method that does that for you.

Comment: @HirenPandit That returns null however :(

Comment: try one thing use `findByStartDateBeforeAndEndDateAfter(Date givenDate, Date givenDate)`

Answer (score 2):

Since you only need the Date object as an equivalent of LocalDate, this should do the trick.

```
default List<AnEntity> findByStartDateAfterAndEndDateBefore(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(endDate);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    return findByStartDateBetween(startDate, cal.getTime());
}
```

Because you want it to include the start, but not the end, and SQL `BETWEEN` is inclusive, we just move the end one day back.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Public List<EntityClass> findData(Date startDate,Date endDate)
   {
     Query<EntityClass> _q = em.createQuery("select a.* from _tableName a 
                         where a.startDate>= :d1 AND a.endDate<= :d2");
    _q.setParameter("d1", startDate, TemporalType.DATE);
    _q.setParameter("d2", endDate, TemporalType.DATE);
    List<EntityClass> result = query.getResultList();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    return result;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use it with no problems like this:

```
findAllByEntityNotNullAndDateBetween(Date begin, Date end);
```

Have you already tried it?

Comment: Not a single date, I have to check with start and end dates. Consider reading the question again ?